# how to do #define macro to do #define "myInt x" "int* x = new int[5]"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can do the following:

```
#define myInt(x) int* x = new int[5]
```

...

```
myInt(dog);

dog[1] = 3;
dog[2] = 5;
```

But I want something like:

```
#define myInt x  int* x = new int[5]
```

so I can do

```
myInt dog;

dog[1] = 3;
dog[2] = 5;
```

What is the proper way to set this up to remove the the function setup??

I was trying to understand how Visual C++ 2010 got away from using pointers in declaring a class...  `cMy *my = new cMy(); --> cMy my;`

Comment: You don't. There's no reason for such a construct.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You need to pass the arguments to an macro expansion in brackets. Also I would not recommend using macro expansion for something like that - this will probably lead to memory leaks and obscure code.

Comment: why not `std::array<int,5> x;`?

Comment: `#define` macros can't be proper. Exceptions arise only a few times in your whole career.

Comment: `cMy my;` creates a `cMy` on the stack, whereas `new cMy` allocates one on the heap. This is standard C++, not specific to Visual C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a macro.  You could do this:

```
typedef int myInt[5];

myInt dog;
dog[1] = 3;
dog[2] = 5;
```

But that means that `dog` is an array, not a pointer.

I'm not sure whether hiding an array type behind a typedef is a good idea, though.

Comment: "I'm not sure whether hiding an array type behind a typedef is a good idea, though" - I think experience with `va_list` proves that it isn't. The reason it's a bad idea is that if someone uses `myInt` as a function parameter then they pretty much need to know whether or not it's an array type, because if it is then weird stuff happens (their function takes a pointer and loses the size information). Since they have to know that really it's an array, not just any old type, you're losing a lot of the benefit of a type alias since you only partly hide the underlying type.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to do, you could also **create a class** and **overload the subscript** ([ ]) **operator**, for instance:

```
class myInt
{
private:
   int m_List[5];

public:
   int& operator[] (const int nIndex)
   {
     return m_List[nIndex];
   }
};
```

Then you could also write:

```
myInt dog;
dog[1] = 3;
dog[2] = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Macros always use parentheses for their parameters. What you are defining with your:

```
#define myInt x  int* x = new int[5]
```

is a replacement from `myInt` to `x  int* x = new int[5]`, and that's hardly what you want.

Stick with the first variant.